# Client-side form validation with javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I just finished making an order form that now needs validation scripts. I'm fairly new to javascript so I'm not sure where to even start. I know that there free validation scripts on the internet, but there are not any that are specific to my needs. The main issue is that I want my form to validate both US and international phone numbers and addresses. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance for answering my amateur question!

Comment: This all looks helpful thanks :-D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small collection of how you can create small javascript functions to validate your form. I would suggest to look into Regular Expressions in Javascript

http://rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0063.html

Answer (score 0):

How about the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) I'v used it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

...or the [MooTools equivalent](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Validator). Either way, it's worth using a framework rather than rolling your own. Internationalization is one of the things that it's best to avoid writing yourself if you can help it.